# Can we count primes in residue classes quickly?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, co.combinatorics, algorithms

Using combinatorial methods (due to Legendre, Lehmer, Meissel, Lagarias, Miller, Odlyzko, Deléglise, Rivat, and probably others) it's possible to count the number of primes up to $N$ quickly -- in time $O(N^{2/3})$ or even $O(N^{3/5})$.  But suppose we wanted to count only the primes $p$ such that $p\equiv x\pmod m$.  Is there a way to calculate this quickly, in time comparable to the above?

Of course if $m$ were large it would be faster to count the primes directly, so you can assume that $m$ is small compared to $N$.

Different methods (e.g. analytic) would also be of interest to me, but my understanding is that these are barely practical even at the largest numbers to which $\pi(N)$ has been computed and are therefore not directly of interest to me.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [Counting primes in residue classes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-247/S0025-5718-04-01649-7/S0025-5718-04-01649-7.pdf) which seems to answer my question.

Comment: I am a programmer, and I found this material as well, but the math is really confusing me, I can't really figure out what y is supposed to be in P2.  Do you know where I can take a look at code (c/c++ preferably) that implements these equations?